# HTML5 Audio Buffer keeps increasing JS Heap size

Tags: javascript, buffer, html5-audio, audio-streaming, shoutcast

I'm using the html5 audio object to stream a podcast. Note that this is a long podcast (~2hrs).

By profiling the memory usage, it looks like the the memory is continuously going up even after garbage collected. This is simple html audio tag. There are no JS logic running. So I'm sure the buffer is consuming the memory.

```
<audio controls="controls">
   <source src="http://eu8.fastcast4u.com:5000/;"/>
</audio>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/henryw4k/mquumgex/1/

My question is eventually at this build-up rate, the page will eventually crash when it runs out of memory, is that correct?

How can I limit/reset this memory build-up? Are there any best practices like stoping and re-playing to clear out the buffer? I don't think there's a way to tinker with the buffer memory for HTML5 Audio.

[image]

Comment: does it crash after a couple hours or not? easier to try than speculate...

Comment: It doesn't crash, but when the apps hit a certain memory threshold, I shut it down because I don't want the entire browser to crash.

Comment: chrome should not crash. i've seen it happen only once or twice ever. let it run; eventually it might decide to release the ram if other tabs need it; but what's the point of towing cars from a half-full parking lot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's no podcast, that's a SHOUTcast stream which runs indefinitely.

Chrome is pretty good about SHOUTcast/Icecast streams.  You can safely run them in an audio tag.  There's enough memory available in most machines that by the time the browser would crash, your users stopped listening anyway.  Even if you do have listeners that listen for days, usually a network connectivity trouble will disconnect them before Chrome will crash anyway.

This has been my experience anyway.  Yours could vary depending on bitrate, codec (different codecs use different libraries with different memory handling), and user behavior.  Try it and see.

> Are there any best practices like stoping and re-playing to clear out the buffer?

If you wanted to clear it out, you can completely remove the audio tag and add a new one.  Simply changing the `src` attribute normally works as well, but you're not changing it in this case, you'd be setting it to the same thing.

> I don't think there's a way to tinker with the buffer memory for HTML5 Audio.

Ah, but there is!  MediaSource Extensions.  You get to request data by whatever means you'd like (such as the Fetch API) and push the data into a buffer for the browser to decode.  That data isn't kept in memory beyond when it is needed, so the chance of crashing due to memory overuse is removed.  Unfortunately, SHOUTcast doesn't support this server-side, so this isn't an option for you.